# Haskell level 1 question, thanks for answers

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and therefore needs some help which i guess is easy for you guys.
I am trying to make a function that does the same as using "!!" for indexes, but the indexes should go from 1 to the length of the list.
This is what i have so far, help function "numberList" and main function "ele"

```
numberList :: [a] -> [(a, Int)]

numberList x = zip x [1..10]

ele :: Int -> [a] -> a
```

End result should look like:

ele 1 [1,2,3] = 1

ele 2 [3,4,5,6] = 4

I have tried some different things with pattern matching, but it doesn't seem to work.
Where do i go from here?

Comment: “I have tried some different things with pattern matching” – great, show what you've tried and where you're stuck. — BTW this is a pretty silly task: `!!` is already unidiomatic as it is, switching it to 1-based indexing makes it even worse.

Comment: Well the thing is i tried pattern matching yes, but ended up using «!!» in my solution anyways. And then i got the infinity error. Also, it is a school task. I wouldn’t do it for fun. I am stuck at finishing the «ele» function, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Before you finish `ele`, I suggest starting `ele`. If you don't want to share your start at `ele` here, the only option is to figure it all out yourself or ask a school resource for help.

Comment: @amalloy But i haven’t started ele. I’ve only declared it. I thought this was a easy solution you guys would see fast. I have described what the behaviour of the function should be. This is a first-week learning Haskell task. Do you not see a solution here?

Comment: If `ele` is just `!!` but with index starting at `1` instead of `0`, how is this not just `ele n lst = lst !! (n - 1)`? Or `ele n = (!! (n - 1))`

Comment: @Chris it is probably like you say, but I think they want us to make the !! but manually? If that’s possible? I dont know. Thanks for answering

Comment: Of course we see a solution here. But that's not helpful, because the obvious goal of this assignment is for you to learn about Haskell. Presumably you can just look at the definition of `!!`, and this is essentially identical to `!!`, so merely *seeing* a solution has not been educational for you. The only other option I (and others here) can see is for you to make your best attempt; then we can help you with any misunderstandings that your attempt makes apparent to us. (We can't know what you don't know without some similar thing!) *That* will be educational. Feeding you code will not be.

Comment: Why did you say you've tried pattern matching then? — Of course it's easy for us, but StackOverflow is not a get-your-homework-done-for-you site. I mean, I could give you a crazy solution like `ele = fmap (last . snd) . (foldl (\(n,r) x -> (n-2 :: Word32, take (fromIntegral n) $ x:r)) . (,[]) . fromIntegral . pred . (*2))`, but how would that be any use for your learning outcome? You have to start an implementation yourself, and ask about problems along the way. If you _can't_ even start, then read your learning material again and more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Consider your two examples:

```
ele 1 [1,2,3] = 1

ele 2 [3,4,5,6] = 4
```

In the first case, because the number was `1`, you returned the head of the list. *Simple.*

```
ele :: Int -> [a] -> a
ele 1 (x:_) = x
```

So we need to get that `2` to `1`. Pretty easy, subtract `1` from it.

But you also need to get `4` to the head of the list. `ele 1 [4, 5, 6]` would handily give you the result you're looking for. This recursion might look like the following, but in the interest of not doing your homework for you, I'll let you fill in the blanks.

```
ele :: Int -> [a] -> a
ele 1 (x:_) = x
ele n (x:xs) = ele (n-1) ??
```